# Apache Camel Context Logs getting printed on Weblogic Console logs instead of file

Tags: spring, log4j, apache-camel

I am using Apace Camel + Spring . I am trying to print my logs from Camel Context  into a file using log4j . I am using Log component in Camel Context as

```
<log  loggingLevel="ERROR" message="Testing Logs with log4j" />
```

I have added log4j.properties also . 
But the logs are getting printed on Weblogic Console instead of file specified in log4j.properties .

log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, applog log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR
log4j.appender.applog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppen‌​der
log4j.appender.applog.File=/application/ABC/appLogs1/appLog.‌​log
log4j.appender.applog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.applog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c %t - %m\n
```

Comment: My entries in log4j.properties are :-                   log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, applog
log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR

log4j.appender.applog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.applog.File=/application/ABC/appLogs1/appLog.log
log4j.appender.applog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.applog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c %t - %m\n

Comment: Can you give me the output of the logs in console ? Are they in same format as the one you have specified in log4j.properties file ?